# I'm unable to connect ATtiny85 and EM18(RFID reader)

Tags: c, arduino, rfid, arduino-ide, attiny

Here is the code in [Arduino online editor](https://create.arduino.cc/editor/warlockmar/fb04bf43-246b-4e9d-8d2b-8686cc07f00c/preview)

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

char tag1[12]={"123456789123"};
char tag2[12]={"123456789456"};
char  var[12]={"000000000000"};
int ok;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
 
Serial.begin(9600);
}
boolean comparetag(char aa[14], char bb[14])
{
  boolean ff = false;
  int fg = 0;
  for (int cc = 0 ; cc < 12 ; cc++)
  {
    if (aa[cc] == bb[cc])
    {
      fg++;
    }
  }
  if (fg == 12)
  {
    ff = true;
  }
  return ff;
}
void check()
{
  ok = 0;
  // if it is 1 we have a match, zero is a read but no match,
  // -1 is no read attempt made
  if (comparetag(var, tag1) == true)
  {
    ok++;
  }
  if (comparetag(var, tag2) == true)
  {
    ok++;
  }
}

void reading_data()
{   ok=-1;
  int k=0;
  char val;
  Serial.println("entre the rfid id");
  while(!Serial.available())
  {
    // It waits
    }
    
  if(Serial.available()>0)
  {     
    for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
  {
    val=Serial.read();
    Serial.print(val);
    var[i]=val;
     while(!Serial.available())
  {
    // It waits
    }
    
    }
   check();
  }
  if (ok > 0) // if we had a match
  { Serial.println('\n');
    Serial.println("Accepted");
    

    ok = -1;
  }
  else if (ok == 0) // if we didn't have a match
  {Serial.println('\n');
    Serial.println("Rejected");

    ok = -1;
  }
  
  }

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
reading_data();
}
```

1. I have used the ATtiny85 library in Arduino IDE
2. I'm getting an error as
   "Serial was not declared in this scope"

Comment: regarding: `char tag1[12]={"123456789123"};
char tag2[12]={"123456789456"};
char  var[12]={"000000000000"}`  those strings are 13 bytes long remember the NUL terminator byte) so, there is the first error

Comment: OT: The posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic numbers are numbers with no basis.  .I.E.. 12, 14.   'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand.  Suggest using `#define` statements or an `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: where is the `main()` function

Comment: strongly suggest reading about the `strcmp() function, those prototype is found in string.h`

Comment: regarding: `{   ok=-1;`  For ease of readability and understanding, strongly suggest placing only one statement per line

Comment: Now the code works but the problem is I have set Serial.begin(9600) but I'm confused about what should I add clk frequency in proteus.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably include those lines:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
```